# How can I send ModelAttribute from HTML (Thymeleaf) to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My BookController:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String showBook(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id, @ModelAttribute("review") Review review){
    if(bookService.findOne(id).isPresent()) {
        model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findOne(id).get());
        System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        return "/books/show";
    }
    return "redirect:/books";
}
```

I want to send this current Book object to CardController and get it in CardController. How I can do that?

I made a form, but I don't know how to send an object

```html
<form th:unless="${#strings.equals(currentUser, 'anonymousUser')}" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/card}">
<button id="add-button" class="fw primary" type="submit">Add book to the card.</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Well you aren't sending anything. You don't send an object you send form fields which will be bound to the model attribute by spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have modeled showBook() as a GET method so you don't need or want to use a form and POST, a link will do the trick and is more appropriate. Try:

```
<a id="add-button" class="fw primary" th:href="@{/books/{id}(id=${book.id})}">Add book to the card.</a>
```

This assumes you have @RequestMapping("/books") on the controller class and the page from which you are creating the link has access to a book in the model that has an id attribute.

If you want a button instead of a link style the link accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

```
<form th:unless="${#strings.equals(currentUser, 'anonymousUser')}" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/card}">
<button id="add-button" class="fw primary" type="submit" th:value="${book.id}">Add book to the card.</button>
</form>



@GetMapping("/card/{id}")
    public String showBook(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id, @ModelAttribute("review") Review review){
        if(bookService.findOne(id).isPresent()) {
            model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findOne(id).get());
            System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
            model.addAttribute("currentUser", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
            return "/books/show";
        }
        return "redirect:/books";
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I mean, it's not a good one, but it's not a verbatim copy paste of the OP's code either.